# php split value with "w"

Tags: php, split

I have a returning values that give me double digits, tripple digits etc. I want to put a "w" in between those numbers. Any kind of help I get on this is greatly appreciated.

```
$value = "444";
```

I want it to give me back this:

```
$value = "4w4w4w";
```

Comment: Add your input and desired output here, question is not clear

Comment: put `;` and explode it using `;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the string into an array and them `implode` it:

```
echo implode("w", str_split("444")) . "w";
```

Comment: try `.` instead of `+` for concatenation ;)

Comment: @Joshua: I knew something was off. Thanks

Comment: this works and i like this solution because it's a 1 liner... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Lets say $inp holds your number.

```
$arr = str_split($inp);
$result = implode('w',$arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

`str_split()` and `implode()` will help.

```
$var = "444";
$array = str_split($var);
$final = implode("w", $array);
```

In this case you `$final = "4w4w4";`, so you might want to append an extra "w" to the end.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short way to do it with regex:

```
$str = '444';
echo preg_replace ( '/(.)/', '$1w', $str );
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $value="444";
 $out='';
 for($i=0;$i<strlen($value);$i++){
    $out.=$value[$i]. "w";
 }
 echo $out;
```

output

```
 4w4w4w
```

Comment: If you are reading char-by-char why store it in array ??? Directly start building the output like : 
~ for (XXX) { $out .= $value[$i]."w"; } ~